# ordinalNet Package in R

Tags: r, regression

I'm using the ordinalNet package in R for prediction.

My Dataset has 51 Variables and 160k observations.

In the `ordinalNet()` function, `x` has to be a covariate matrix and `y` has to be a factor.

If I interchange the X as a covariate matrix, it will have 51 rows and 51 columns.
The response variable has 160k observations, so it's showing an error due to mismatched dimensions.

```
fit_exp<-ordinalNet(x, y, family="cumulative", link="logit")

**Error in ordinalNet(x, y, family = "cumulative", link = "logit") : 
  x and y dimensions do not match.**
```

How should I approach this differently? I'm new to R.

Comment: Please read: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example

Comment: How that post applies here: the first step to answering this is trying to reproduce the same error with a smaller data set, or a data set that comes with base r. Then, if that hasn't solved your question, post the example that reproduces the error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error message explains by itself:

```
x and y dimensions do not match.
```

You can check your x and y dimensions with:

```
nrow(x) ; length(y)
```